# Smooth Scrolling - CSS Tricks - Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify, smooth-scrolling

I just implemented the script of the [Smooth Scrolling by CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) in my shopify store site. but it doesn't work for me :(

here's the script of the smooth scroll

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($) {
     $j('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $j(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $j('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $j('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
   });
 </script>
```

and this another code for my slick sliders

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($) {
      $j('.obs_store_wall_slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        fade: true,
        draggable: false,
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        cssEase: 'linear'
      });

    $j('.obs_store_wall_banner_slider').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        draggable: true,
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        cssEase: 'linear'
      });
   });
 </script>
```

to see live action , visit [my store](https://originboardshop.com/pages/billabong-store-wall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, i cannot believe it . the script is not working due to my html syntax , i put a "#" in the section id :D